# time comparison between night time and morning time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table that contains two column those contains a integer value

**1- StartTime as int
2-EndTime as int**

Now i have to compare hour value from current time with these times.

I am Executing the query if hour value of Current time is greater than starttime and hour value of Current time is less than Endtime IN **24HOURS FORMAT**.

Now the issue is.

**If StartTime = 19 and
Endtime = 7(morning)**

If Current hour value returns 20

then   20 > 19 its true  but 20<7 this value getting false....

20 is coming between evening 7 o'clock and morning 7 o'clock...but this query is getting false exception...

Please help me on this.....

**I wll be very very highly obliged to u all.....**

Again i am explaining this issue in detail

DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) --- this function will return me a single hour value

Like at 8:00:00PM this will return just 20

in my table i have stored starttime and endtime as Integer value

like  starttime - 19
      endtime - 7

so now that 20 will compare with both values like

20 > 19  ---- true
20 < 7  ----- this gonna be false

but as per my scenario it should come correct because i am checking night 8 o'clock with morning 7 o'clock    ...... night 8 comes between night 7 and morning 7(this is what i have defined in starttime and endtime)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Pls explain more effectively.

Comment: Do you have date data for starttime and endtime?

Comment: If you can change your code so that you store the full date instead of just the hour you will make your life so much simpler.

Comment: You say "_i have stored starttime and endtime as Integer value_" and if you don't have date data you can not compare times reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @current_Hour INT
SELECT @current_hour = DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())
--SELECT @current_hour = 20

DECLARE @startTime INT
SET @startTime = 19
DECLARE @endtime INT
set @endTime = 7

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @startTime <= @endTime THEN 
            CASE WHEN @current_hour BETWEEN @startTime AND @endtime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN @current_hour BETWEEN @endtime AND @startTime THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have date data and if CurrentTime is greater than StartTime and EndTime lesser than StartTime you can think your EndTime equals 24+EndTime (or you can ignore EndTime validation) but there are so many possibility outside of this case. You should explain your problem.

If date is not important for you

```
WHERE
(
    @CurrentTime > StartTime 
    AND StartTime > EndTime
)
OR
(
    @CurrentTime > StartTime 
    AND StartTime < EndTime
    AND @CurrentTime < EndTime
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple:

```
@Date > StartTime
AND (
    @Date < EndTime
OR
    EndTime < Startime
)
```

Note that it (and NOTHING) won't work if @Date can aslo be "next day in the morning".

Comment: But you'd definitively better use Date instead of Int right away.